# Copying DynamoDB table to S3 every time table is updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table that's fairly large and is updated infrequently and sporadically (maybe once a month).  When it is updated it happens in a large batch, i.e. a large number of items are inserted with batch update.

Every time the DynamoDB table changes, I want to convert the contents to a custom JSON format and store the result in S3 to be more easily accessed by clients (since the most common operation is downloading the entire table, and DynamoDB scans are not as efficient).

Is there a way to convert the table to JSON and copy to S3 after every batch update?

I saw Data Pipelines (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-exportddbtos3.html) but it seems like this is triggered manually or on a schedule.  I also looked at DynamoDB Streams, but it seems like an event is inserted for every record changed.  I want to do the conversion and copying to S3 only once per batch update.

Comment: How do you define a "batch update"? Are they all updated in one API call? If not, what would define the start/end of a batch?

Comment: Also, do you need to keep historical snapshots of the data, or do you want S3 to just reflect the current state of your DynamoDB table?

Comment: They will be updated in one API call using BatchWriteItem: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

However BatchWriteItem has a size limit, so most update table API calls will probably make several BatchWriteItem requests

Comment: I just want S3 to reflect the current state of the table.  I'm using S3 to make the "get all items" operation more efficient, since most of the time the clients need to get the whole contents of the table and convert it to a different format, so since the table is updated infrequently it seems more efficient to do this once for each update.

Comment: Can you just have the service that is calling `BatchWriteItem` call a Lambda function after it is done (or maybe post a message to an SNS topic which triggers a Lambda)? Then the Lambda function could query the data and write it to S3 in whatever format you want.

Comment: Yes, that's my current solution.  The downside is that for every service/API that's writing to the database, I'd need to make sure to call the updateS3 lambda function after it finishes, so it seems not quite as safe as having a listener to the dynamodb stream changes or something like that.   However perhaps there's no real way to know when the API is done writing outside of the API itself.